# IMDBpy getting screen information

Tags: python, imdbpy

```
import imdb    
ia = imdb.IMDb()
avatar = ia.get_movie("0120667")
ia.update(avatar, 'business')
print avatar['business']
```

That returns the whole list of gross, aswell as screenings for each country. But how do i get out the screening information only? And for only 1 country. in this example the information i want to get is (USA) (10 July 2005) (3,602 Screens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import imdb
import re

ia = imdb.IMDb()
avatar = ia.get_movie("0120667")
ia.update(avatar, 'business')
opening_weekends = avatar['business']['opening weekend']

def parseDate(date):
    result = {}

    if re.match(".*\d{4}$", date):
        result['year'] = date[-4:]

    m = re.match(".*(?P<month>January|February|March|April|May|June|July|"
                "August|September|October|November|December).*", date, re.I)
    if m:
        result['month'] = m.group('month').lower()

        # try to grab date too then
        daymatch = re.match("^(?P<day>\d{1,2}).*", date)

        if daymatch:
            result['day'] = daymatch.group('day')       
    return result

def parseBudget(amount):
    """
    assumptions: 
    - currency is always before the number
    - no fractions
    """

    # find index first number
    for i in range(len(amount)):
        if amount[i] in "0123456789":
            amount_idx = i
            break

    currency = amount[:amount_idx].strip()
    amount = re.sub("\D", "", amount[amount_idx:])

    return amount, currency

def parseWeekendGross(gross_text):
    g = gross_text.split(' (')
    if not len(g) == 4:
        return ""
    amount, currency = parseBudget(g[0])
    country = g[1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')')
    date = parseDate(g[2].lstrip('(').rstrip(')'))
    day, month, year = date['day'], date['month'], date['year']
    screens = re.sub("\D", "", g[3])
    if not screens:
        screens = "''"

    return amount, currency, country, day, month, year, screens

for entry in opening_weekends:
    amount, currency, country, day, month, year, screens = parseWeekendGross(entry)
    if country == "USA":
        print("Country: %s" % country)
        print("Date: %s %s %s" % (day, month, year))
        print("Screens: %s" % screens)
        break
```

The above code gives me the following result:

```
Country: USA
Date: 10 july 2005
Screens: 3602
```

The functions to parse the data are copied from this project: [pyIRDG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyirdg/)